# Memory optimization when selecting from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather large pandas dataframe (1.7G) from which I am selecting some columns to do some computaton (find maximum value of the three selected columns). It seems that this operation is memory intensive. I am trying to find a way to avoid this memory overhead.

For the purpose to this question, I a simplifying the dataframe and using fake data. My code and the memory footprint is shown below,

```
from memory_profiler import profile
import pandas as pnd
import random


@profile
def main():
    cols = [chr(i) for i in range(65,91)]
    d = {}
    n = 1000000
    for c in cols:
        d[c] = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(n)]
    df = pnd.DataFrame(d)
    items = ['A','F','G']
    a = df[items]
    b = a.max(axis=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     6     42.3 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
     7                             def main():
     8     42.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       cols = [chr(i) for i in range(65,91)]
     9     42.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       d = {}
    10     42.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       n = 1000000
    11    240.6 MiB    198.3 MiB       for c in cols:
    12    240.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           d[c] = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(n)]
    13    446.7 MiB    206.1 MiB       df = pnd.DataFrame(d)
    14    446.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       items = ['A','F','G']
    15    469.7 MiB     23.1 MiB       a = df[items]
    16    469.8 MiB      0.1 MiB       b = a.max(axis=0)
```

In the above operation, it seems that df[items] uses up 23MB of memory. I am speculating that this because it is making a copy of the df and placing it in 'a'.

Is there a way get rid of this memory overhead when selecting columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas returns copies for most operations. Certain selection operations can return a *view*, in that the memory may not be copied and is an underlying numpy view. This is in general controlled by numpy. A taking operation like you are doing, (e.g. a non-consecutive) slice, will never give a view.

However, more to the point, this doesn't actually matter, as soon as the reference to the variable is release the memory will be garbage collected.

What is your goal here?

Comment: I am dealing with a dataPanel that is 1.7G. When I do this selection operation at multiple place in my program, I end up with an overhead that causes my 8G machine to hang and freeze.

Comment: May be I should increase my memory on my machine

Comment: you could do that, or work with the data in a HDF file. Make sure your dtypes are correct (e.g. not object, except for strings).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing calculations, you probably don't need to select the columns out into new variables and create the copies.

Just apply the function directly - I guess this will take more CPU as it's calculating all the maxes, then just getting the ones you want, but doesn't create a new variable.

```
df.max()[['A','F','G']]
```

Or try a quick loop through the columns you need the max for, using simple selection of one column at a time to try to get a view returned (as you can't use the complex slice and get a view).